# Sending an email to user for verification using WSO2

Tags: smtp, wso2, email-verification, wso2-identity-server

I am completely new to wso2. I am trying to send an email to user for verification of new account which I(admin) am creating for a particular company(not through gmail) in the default PRIMARY domain. Using that link they should be able to login and set new password. For this the steps I followed are :

(1)Setting identity-mgt.properties file

```
# Identity listener is enable

Identity.Listener.Enable=true

# Enable email sending function when recovering the account and verifying the user creation

Notification.Sending.Enable=true
Notification.Expire.Time=7200

# Enable internal email sending module. If "false", email sending data would be available to application via webservice. Then application can send the email using its own email sender 

Notification.Sending.Internally.Managed=true

# Enable verification of account creation. When self registration is done,  user would be verified by sending email (confirmation link) to user's email account
 
UserAccount.Verification.Enable=true

UserAccount.Recovery.Enable=false


# Whether user can do the verification or not. If value is defined for role, Then the email is sent to users that have been assigned to this role. Not for the user who is registered.

UserAccount.Verification.Role=

# Whether captcha verification is done by identity server or application level

Captcha.Verification.Internally.Managed=true

# Whether temporary password are used when creating users or recovering accounts

Temporary.Password.Enable=false
Temporary.Password.Default.Value=password
Temporary.Password.OneTime=false
Temporary.Password.Expire.Time=0

# Enable authentication rules other than password check 

Authentication.Policy.Enable=true

# Enable following checking on authenication.  By default account lock check is enable 

Authentication.Policy.Check.Account.Exist=false 
Authentication.Policy.Check.Account.Lock=false
Authentication.Policy.Check.OneTime.Password=false
Authentication.Policy.Check.Password.Expire=false

# Configuration to build an authentication policy

Authentication.Policy.Password.Expire.Time=0
# If account verification is not enabled, following property will decide where user must be lock or not after user is created 
Authentication.Policy.Account.Lock.On.Creation=false
Authentication.Policy.Account.Lock.Time=0
Authentication.Policy.Account.Lock.On.Failure=false
Authentication.Policy.Account.Lock.On.Failure.Max.Attempts=0

# Define pluggable extension points

Identity.Mgt.Random.Password.Grenerator=org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.password.DefaultPasswordGenerator
Identity.Mgt.User.Data.Store=org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.store.UserStoreBasedIdentityDataStore
Identity.Mgt.Notification.Sending.Module.1=org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.mail.DefaultEmailSendingModule
Identity.Mgt.User.Recovery.Data.Store=org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.store.RegistryRecoveryDataStore


# Define password policy enforce extensions

Password.policy.extensions.1=org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.policy.password.DefaultPasswordLengthPolicy
Password.policy.extensions.1.min.length=6
Password.policy.extensions.1.max.length=12
Password.policy.extensions.2=org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.policy.password.DefaultPasswordNamePolicy
Password.policy.extensions.3=org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.policy.password.DefaultPasswordPatternPolicy
Password.policy.extensions.3.pattern=^((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%&*])).{0,100}$
```

(2) Setting axis2.xml file....
In this I uncommented the transportSender name="mailto"  section and added the parameter values. I also uncommented transportReceiver name="mailto" section .
Parameters in transportSender name="mailto" section are :-

```
<transportSender name="mailto"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportSender">
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.from"></parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.user"></parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.password"></parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.host"></parameter>

        <parameter name="mail.smtp.port"></parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.starttls.enable"></parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.auth"></parameter>
    </transportSender>
```

(3) This is the default setting of some part of the email-admin-config.xml file

```
<configuration type="askPassword">
  <targetEpr></targetEpr>
  <subject>WSO2 Carbon - Password Change for New Account</subject>
  <body>
Hi {first-name}

Please change your password for the newly created account : {user-name}. Please click the link below to create the password.

http://localhost:9443/InfoRecoverySample/infoRecover/verify?confirmation={confirmation-code}

If clicking the link doesn't seem to work, you can copy and paste the
link into your browser's address window.
  </body>
  <footer>
Best Regards,
WSO2 Carbon Team
http://www.wso2.com
  </footer>
  <redirectPath></redirectPath>
</configuration>
```

Now, when I create a new user by selecting "Ask a password" option I get this error. But the user is getting created in the default domain.

**"Could not add user PRIMARY/addUser. Error is: Error while doPostAddUser"**

I searched regarding the complete process in many sites but did not get any proper documentation regarding what each parameter in different files does so as to customize for my use.

Please let me know where did I go wrong and also what all other things I need to configure.
Also, sources required for understanding all parameters.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

in the `wso2server` script.

Mail sending worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the following parameter is set to false in `repository\conf\security\identity-mgt.properties`:

```
Authentication.Policy.Account.Lock.On.Creation=false
```

Comment: Following http://mail.wso2.org/mailarchive/dev/2014-December/040210.html i added the folowwing claim mapping :
Description: Identity Password TimeStamp
Claim Uri: http://wso2.org/claims/identity/passwordTimestampMapped Attribute: facsimileTelephoneNumber

There seems to be a problem (bug ?) with the UI : Attribute value contains null juste after mapping creation and i had to modify mapping and overwrite null with facsimileTelephoneNumber
After that, the creation process worked nicely